# Why didn't delete 'it' in the sentence: What was it about snails that made the writer collect

Tags: pronouns

> What was it about snails that made the writer collect them for his friend on that day in particular?

Why didn't delete **it** in the sentence above?

Comment: _It_ refers to the fact concerning snails which made the writer decide to collect some. The sentenced would not be valid without it,.

Comment: Because we have to indicate that there was *a thing* about snails, and that thing is referred to as "it", and the question is not grammatically correct without it.  Just like how your question is not grammatically correct: it should be "Why didn't **the writer** delete *it*"

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, it {In the sentence} wants to talk about the object{The reason which got the writer to collect snails.}

if we delete it, the object will be changed from the reason to the snails.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the "it" is a bit redundant, because both "what" and "it" refer to the same thing. But this is a common phrase that is worth learning:

> What is/was it that ...
> What is/was it about ... that ...

and this phrase is used with all of those parts, like a formula.

If you remove only the word "it", I would argue that logically, it would still mean the same thing. It's just not said or written that way in my experience, so it would be confusing.

But you can remove other words in addition to "it", to rephrase it in another way:

> What about snails made ...

One reason to use the "What was it about X that Y" version is that it puts emphasis on the question of finding the reason for "Y".

---

As for why "What was about ___ that ___" is not used, I would guess it's related to the fact that "what" and "it" in your example don't refer to ordinary objects, but to a quality, aspect, fact, reason, advantage, problem, etc. When "what" refers to something tangible instead, I don't see a problem with "What was ___ that ___":

> What was on the table that made her smile?
> What was it on the table that made her smile?

I also don't see a problem when "was" is part of a continuous tense:

> What was happening that made him run away?
> What was it that was happening?